# Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling messes up screen geometry size in 4K Monitor at 4K Resolution

Tags: qt, opengl, dpi

I have a QT application that I need to run both on low and high resolution monitors. I'm using

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

to set the scaling of the Qt Window.

And my current resolution from my 4K monitor is 3840 * 2160. I'm running windows. Now I'm trying get the current screen size with this.

```
QDesktopWidget qdw;
QRect mainScreenSize = qdw.screenGeometry(0);

int height1 = mainScreenSize.height();
int width1 = mainScreenSize.width();
std::cout << width1 << "\n";
std::cout << height1 << "\n";
```

But this prints out 1920 * 1080. It does this only for 3840 * 2160 which is the full resolution for the monitor and this happens only when Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling this is enabled.

If HighDpiScaling is not enabled, then it prints every single resolution perfectly be it anything from 1920 * 1080 or 2560 * 1440 or whatever!

I need to get the actual screen size with EnableHighDpiScaling enabled, so I can scale my GL screen based on the current screen resolution.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm no Qt expert, but I rather suspect that the purpose of the High DPI scaling setting is so that *Qt* will scale your stuff *for you*. That is, you pretend that everything is rendering at 1080p or whatever, and Qt makes it work correctly for the actual resolution. So what you want seems to be at cross-purposes.

Comment: No its not actually doing that for the GL screen in the QT window. It scales the overall Qt Window, but the viewport of the GL screen stays the same. By which I mean the objects in the middle of the GL screen in 1920 x 1080 goes to the bottom left 1/4th in the new scaled window in 3840 x 2160 with HIGHDPI enabled..

Comment: Right. That's because Qt *cannot* affect what happens in OpenGL. It can't rescale the OpenGL stuff. But Qt can still *pretend* that the OpenGL window is 1080p. That's why I say it's working at cross-purposes: you can't make Qt do rescaling for a rendering system that Qt doesn't own.

Comment: Thats exactly where my question lies. So that's why I'm trying to get the actual screen resolution based on which I can scale the GL window. But when I enable HIGHDPI, I'm not getting the correct resolution for 3840 x 2160. It gives me the half only for the maximum resolution. Any other resolution other than 4K works fine.

Comment: Or what is the best way to scale GL as well with QT ?